# Ubuntu Installer 14.04 shuts down while installing

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I have a problem that seems to be going unanswered.

I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 64-Bit installer and flashed it to a disk. I installed this on a home-built computer with no problems. So I decided to install this on my HP Pavilion g6. Whenever it starts installing, the installer disk shuts down the computer.

Here are the steps to reproduce it:

Turn on the computer with the disk inserted.

Let Ubuntu start up and select "Install Ubuntu"

Select "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7"

Connect to the internet

Select "Download Updates" and "Install Third-party Software"

Start install

The screen turns purple and says "Please remove disk and press Enter to continue"

I do what it says and it restarts the computer.

The computer boots up normally into Windows 7 with no GRUB

Comment: You can bypass "download updates" and "third party software" till after the successful install. This way it's less variables to complicate troubleshooting bad install.

Comment: I'm confused by a couple of things about your question. First, I can't get any 14.04 install CD to ask me the question "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7" on either of two computers. Are you sure about what version of the Ubuntu installer you are using? What does the README.diskdefines file say? It's my understanding that Installing Ubuntu inside Windows 7 involves using Wubi, and further that Wubi is pretty much deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair the GRUB with [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

**Install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

*open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

**Using Boot-Repair**

Launch Boot-Repair from either :

- The Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen) or
- System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
- or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

- [Official website of Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/)
- [Topic "Boot-repair: Graphical tool to repair the PC boot in 1 click !"](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10871917#post10871917) - on Ubuntu forum, for any questions/comments.
- [HOWTO : easily create a Boot-Info summary](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info)

Comment: The problem is that I don't have Ubuntu installed...
Do you want me to do it from the disc?

Comment: Yes, run from the disc or USB